# How to do bulk inserts with JpaRepository with dynamic batch_size i.e batch_size is not known

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working in a java spring boot API where I need to insert a bulk data in my database. I know how could I achieve this.

To get a bulk insert with Sring Boot and Spring Data JPA you need only two things:

- set the option `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50`
- use `saveAll()` method of your repo with the list of entities prepared for inserting.

What I want to know is that how could I achieve dynamic batch_size i.e. in some classes, I need to save/insert just 5 to 10 records, while in some classes this number could be 200 to 500 or more records.

Now, **How could I achieve this dynamic batch_size option**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically change the `batch_size` just by using the `EntityManager` AP Ioption during runtime but you can have some sort of control:

**1)** Set the batch_size to the highest expected value (500 i.e.)

**2)** Set these props in order for hibernate not to try to use the previously done `save/update` statements.

```
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updatest=true
```

**3)** Use `save` instead of `saveAll`. Loop through your list and flush every number of times that are relevant to the class being saved:

```
int = flushAfterThisNumber = 10;

for ( int i=0; i<entities.length; i++ ) {
    session.save(entities[i]);
    if ( i % flushAfterThisNumber == 0 ) { 
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is a workaround possible, but you need to create a custom repo so that you will be able to inject an `EntityManager`, then unwrap the Hibernate `Session` and then have access to dynamic setting of `batch_size`.

```
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomCustomerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void saveAllInBatch(List<Ent> entities, int batchSize) {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.setJdbcBatchSize(batchSize);

        em.saveAll(entities);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using  SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS. Could I still be able to use session.save or session.flush/clear.

Comment: if you repos exptend JpaRepository then you will call.. repo.flush()

Comment: Ok, I understand. Yes, I have to use repo.save / repo.flush. Since I extend my repos from JpaRepository. So there is no dynamic option. Max size could be around 1000 right now and it could be increase in future.

Comment: Chech the update. But be carefull not to overuse the unwrap feature.

Comment: Which will give more performance save with for loop or saveAll with Max batch_size.

Comment: Go for the loop